# Make my css menu stay on top of the screen?

Tags: html, css

like in http://facebook.com they have a nav bar type thing that stays at the top of the page how can i do that with my code. i have my css advanced menu working except for that one problem. well here is my link to my jsfiddle

[Js fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BdHNs/)

**Main Parts of css**

```
#cssmenu ul { margin: 0; padding: 0;}
#cssmenu li { margin: 0; padding: 0;}
#cssmenu a { margin: 0; padding: 0;}
#cssmenu ul {list-style: none;}
#cssmenu a {text-decoration: none;}
#cssmenu { height: 42px; background-color: rgb(35,35,35); box-shadow: 0px 2px 3px rgba(0,0,0,.4);}
```

now if im not mistaken this has to be done with this part if not check the JsFiddle

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Add the following to your menu css:

```
#cssmenu {
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
```

That's basically how they do it.

Comment: Please note that this will hide the top of any content on the page and is not a complete answer

Comment: Indeed, @josh123a123 — so how do you fix the element beneath so that its content begins just below the menu?

Comment: I fixed this by adding a 'dummy' spacer element above the content and with the same height as my actual bar. The spacer is hidden (instead of the content) behind the real navbar it just scrolls up with the content.

Answer (score 5):

Add fixed property

```
 #cssmenu {
          position:fixed;
 }
```

Comment: It was quite obvious to set the top and left to 0 as you always want that to be on the top. So did not add that in the answer.

Answer (score 4):

Just a thought, don't you need to add `z-index: 1000;` so that it floats over all the items on the page?

Comment: I had issue where `position:fixed` worked and everything on page was kept under the banner, except one map which would stay over it. So setting `z-index:2000;` worked. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

It can be done if you use :

```
 position:fixed;
```

Comment: tryed it it disfigured the menu bar

Answer (score 1):

Use this css for set your nav bar fixed on top.

```
 #cssmenu {
   position:fixed;
   top: 0;
   margin:auto;
   left: 0;
   right: 0;
   width: 100%;
  }
```

Here the demo: http://jsfiddle.net/SkuhZ/

Comment: i alredy got it working i ticked Dineshkani but u can help me with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16910096/make-my-search-box-show-up-in-the-right-position

Answer (score 0):

Just these 3 would do..

```
position: fixed;
top: 0;
width: auto;
```

Comment: You could elaborate on this by adding information like which selector these should be applied to and how these work together to achieve the desired effect.