# Make my search box show up in the right position

Tags: html, css

how do i make the search box in the center of the nav bar? you will see what i mean below with the image.. ill post my css code for the search box below the image ..

[image]

```css
   #advsearch {
   }
   #advsearch input[type="text"] {
       background: url(/images/search-dark.png) no-repeat 10px 6px #444;
       border: 0 none;
       font: bold 12px Arial, Helvetica, Sans-serif;
       color: #777;
       width: 150px;
       padding: 6px 15px 6px 35px;
       -webkit-border-radius: 20px;
       -moz-border-radius: 20px;
       border-radius: 20px;
       text-shadow: 0 2px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
       -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1), 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2) inset;
       -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1), 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2) inset;
       box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1), 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2) inset;
       -webkit-transition: all 0.7s ease 0s;
       -moz-transition: all 0.7s ease 0s;
       -o-transition: all 0.7s ease 0s;
       transition: all 0.7s ease 0s;
   }
   #advsearch input[type="text"]:focus {
       width: 200px;
   }
```

thanks so much in advance :) if u want maybe we can work on my website together?

also here is a [Js Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/y5Fhc/) just incase you need it dont mind the images not being there it should not make a diffrence

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you need to modify some css code.

```
#cssmenu > ul > li > a {
    color: #A0A0A0;
    font-family: Verdana,'Lucida Grande';
    font-size: 15px;
    /*line-height: 70px;
    padding: 0;*/
    position: relative;
    top: 7px;
    transition: color 0.15s ease 0s;
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/y5Fhc/8/

Answer (score 0):

anchor in not needed in the li of search box and I have added a class in the li of search box to make it center of the nav bar.

css

```
li.search{
    line-height:40px;
}
```

html

```
<li class='active search'><span>
     <form method="get" action="/search" id="advsearch">
       <input name="q" type="text" size="40" placeholder="Search..." />
     </form>
</li>
```

[jsFiddle File](http://jsfiddle.net/y5Fhc/7/)